# El valor del output es siempre null. PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema. El procedimiento devuelve un valor output (tipo boleano) y cuando lo recojo en el codigo php es siempre nulo. Alguna solucion??

Gracias!

PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO DE MYSQL:

```
BEGIN    
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE usuario LIKE p_usuario AND 
         contrasena LIKE p_contrasena) THEN
        SET p_salida = 1;
ELSE
        SET p_salida = 0;
  END IF;    
END
```

CODIGO PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['txtUsuario']))
{
// Almacenar los datos de la base de datos en variables
$usuario = "root";
//$contrasena
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "proyecto";

// Crear la conexion con el servior de la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario); 

//Comprobar conexion 

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
die("Conexion fallida:" . $conexion->connect_error);}

// Crear conexion con la base de datos
$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos);

// Declarar como variables los input 
$usuario=$_POST['txtUsuario'];
$contrasena=$_POST['txtContrasena'];


$sqlpro = "CALL pr_login($usuario,$contrasena,'@p_salida')";
$rdo=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT @p_salida as salida");
echo $rdo;
      $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rdo);
      if($fila['salida']==1)
           echo 'BUENO';
      else
        echo 'MALO';

 }
 else
 ?>
 <html>
 <body>

<form action="" method="post">
    Usuario: 
    <input name="txtUsuario" type="text" /><br/>
    Contraseña:
    <input name="txtContrasena" type="password" /><br/>
    <input name="txtIniciarSesion" type="submit" value="Iniciar sesion" 
/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Me parece un poco extraño que la persona que respondió supiera que estas realizando el query incorrecto aquí : $rdo=mysqli_query(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estas ejecutando el procedimiento almacenado. Debes de utilizar la sentencia mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlpro); antes de recoger el valor output.

Un saludo compañero

Comment: ¿ y como supiste que ese es el cambio adecuado ? se supone que realiza : $rdo=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT @p_salida as salida"); pero no ha brindado información acerca de que desea obtener como resultado?

Comment: Como ves, tiene definida una llamada de un procedimiento almacenado con un parámetro OUTPUT llamado p_salida. Seguido a esto tiene una select del mismo parametro y lo quiere almacenar en una variable. Si esta variable no tiene ningun valor recogera un nulo. Por lo cual me hizo pensar que tal vez queria ejecutar el procedimiento que tenia definido justamente al lado. Espero que esta aclaración te sea de ayuda